# Graph calendar change notification sent for series master when instance is edited

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-notifications

I have created a subscription to my Outlook calendar. When a specific instance of a recurring event is edited in Outlook, the notification that is sent to my notification url is for the series master event (not the particular instance that was updated).

I am trying to determine if the change was to the series or to a specific instance.

Is there any way to find out from the notification (or the series master) what caused the notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the instances for an event (using the Graph API), the exceptions come back first (before the occurrences).

Therefore, if the series master did not change, I check to see if there are any instances where Type == "Exception". If there are, I delete them from outlook so they don't come back the next time I query for the event instances.

NOTE- I am still trying to find a solution to retrieve cancelledOccurrences, those instances of a recurring event that are deleted (or declined) from Outlook and therefore are not returned when querying the Graph API for event instances (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of doing the same! Any luck with the declines or deletes?